# Avoid kafka disk to became 100% used by Cron job

Tags: apache-kafka

We want to suggest the following based on our issues on kafka disks

Each cluster include 3 kafka machines , while each kafka include disk with ~15 T

Because we have many issues that disk increased to 100% used capacity ( kafka Retention from some reason not works as should be )

Then we think about cron job that will run on kafka machines every min

And when kafka disk size will be for example - ~90%

then cron job will stop all kafka brokers ( kafka service )

And by this we avoid the kafka disk to became 100% , ( as all know when disk is 100% then the purging process will not works )

Please share your opinion

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to set your retention based on the space available, or size your disks based on the space requirements?

Comment: we set retention , but still we get the fact disk comes to 100% used until we solve the problem about the retention , we want to avoid this issue by my suggestion ,

Comment: any way what you think about me suggestion ?

Comment: I will give you example - we set the log.retention.bytes to 110G , we calculate this value accruing to the topics  , but from some reason purging not works , any way to validate why purging not works?

Comment: @Judy How fast does your partitions grow? Please keep in mind that the retention-policy isn't a hard but more a soft limit. Maybe you can provide your broker config.

Comment: @Judy Did I get it right: The log.retention.bytes is 110G on a 15TB disk (less than 10%)? The kafka-logs (the segment files) sum to which amount?

Comment: Did you maybe have a different retention policy for the different topics?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183179/discussion-between-judy-and-tobish).